# If $S_2$ is an orientable surface and $\varphi : S_2 \to S_1 $ is a diffeomorphism, then $S_1$ is orientable

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces

> Let $S_2$ be an orientable surface and let $$ \varphi : S_2 \to S_1 $$ be a diffeomorphism. Prove that $S_1$ is orientable.

---

**My attempt:**

As $S_2$ is orientable, then exists a differentiable field of normal unit vectors $N : S_2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ over $S_2$. Moreover, $N\circ \varphi : S_1 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a differentiable field of normal unit vectors over $S_1$ because $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism. This implies that $S_1$ is orientable.

What do you think about my proof?

Comment: Are surfaces for you by definition contained in $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: In any case, $N\circ\phi$ does not map a point $p$ of $S_1$ to a vector normal to $S_1$ at $p$, in general. For example, consider two non-parallel planes in $\mathbb R^3$, which are certainly diffeomorphic.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes are contained in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez but if one of that surfaces are orientable then the point $p$ in $S_1$ will be sent to a point $S_2$ by the diffeomorphism and as S_2 is diffeomorphic, you can use the $N$ function. (i think)

Comment: The existence of a diffeomorphism $\phi$ between the two surfaces means that they can be identified as smooth manifolds. In other words, basically any property of $S_2$ can be transferred to $S_1$ via $\varphi$. Think about an isomorphism between two groups for example. More specifically, if $S_2$ is orientable, there exists an atlas of $S_2$ whose charts are all compactible with each other (the determinant of the transition map is always positive). Do the images of the charts in $S_2$ under $\varphi$ form an atlas of $S_1$? Does the compatibility still hold for the charts in $S_2$?

Comment: @rcorder, I suggest you try to implement your idea in my example of the two planes.